# error when inflating view. Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar-compat

onCreateView() - error when inflating view. Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment

Hi guys,
has any got a clue how to debug such errors?

I found several posts from people having same error but I just can't find any of solutions working.

Basically I have a project which is quite complex, if FragmentActivity with Viewpager and Fragments as pages which one of them has got map fragment which is support map fragment but extended by map extensions project.

What I now wanted to do was to get rid or sherlock fragment and replace it by actionbar compat  project.

How ever app is crashing immediately after starting when inflating map fragment. 
I have no idea why and just do not have a clue ho wto debug and find out what's wrong. I need some general help how to find out problem. The code of the app is soo big to paste it here and also commenting out any little thing in the app breaks the app in several places so finding what the problem is kind of impossible.
Any clues how to get to root of such error?

Thanks a lot.

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mapParent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal" >

<!--     <fragment -->
<!--         android:id="@+id/map" -->
<!--         android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
<!--         android:layout_height="match_parent" -->

<!--         class="pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.SupportMapFragment" /> -->

<fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

and onCreateview()

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("map_page", "onCreateView() called");
    // thi is funky workarount for map fragment as it it not properly restored itself
    if (view != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(view);
    }
    try {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_page, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {
        Log.w("map_page", "onCreateView() - error when inflating view. "+e.getMessage());
        /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
    }





    return view;
}
```

Comment: Post the full XML file as well as the onCreateView

Comment: Here is the beginning of XML as it is quite long and rest is not interesting. also the error clearly says the problem is on line 15 which is <fragment element. here is the xml

Comment: Thanks Everett you made me to find the problem. As soon as I pasted onViewCreated() I noticed there is try catch and warning log which was printing the error in the logcat, I removed it and got full error not only errorMessage(). After this I could see in the logcat that I need to include <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> to manifest. it must be something new. the version in play store released month ago hasn't got it yet. Due to this try catch I was blind and you made me to see it ;o) thnaks again

Answer (score 0):

if you catch exceptions print full error stack in logcat not only error message ;o) and then add this to your manifest

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```